# Populating 3rd party web forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, webforms

I'd like to know if its possible to complete a form on a third party website using data sent from my webserver?

I'm working with a taxi company and they have an online booking system I'd like to interact with, so someone can sign in to my site and use data they have already entered to schedule a a taxi by autopopulating the taxi companies online form.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your needs you want a **Headless Browser** to interact with website.

Take a look:

http://phantomjs.org/

and

http://casperjs.org/